# append list of strings to a new list in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, typeerror

I am receiving a type error that I do not understand. I'd like to compile a list of the better/worse than average months with the month names in another list to label them. Still very new to this so I bet there is a really intuitive way to do this that I don't know yet.
Comments are the types (to be) included:

```
good= [] #---- float
bad= [] #---- float
goodmonths = [] #---- string (month names)
badmonths = [] #---string

for i in net: #----float
    if i > average: #---also float
        good.append(i)
        goodmonths.append(months[i])
    elif i < average:
        bad.append(i)
        badmonths.append(months[i])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-136-362a333d8546> in <module>()
      6     if i > average:
      7         good.append(i)
----> 8         goodmonths.append(months[i])
      9     elif i < average:
     10         bad.append(i)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

I'd like to receive an output like this:

```
Good months:
Jan: 1292.23
Feb: 1738.09
etc... ditto for badmonths
```

Comment: What is `months[1292.23]` supposed to be? Why are you trying to append that to `goodmonths`?

Comment: What is the value of `net`?

Comment: The idea is to take  the value from an existing list (net) and add it to a new  list (good). Because each value in net[] corresponds to a month, I also want to have the month (i.e index) from the previous list stored somewhere, that was the idea for the goodmonths list.

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like you are trying to integrate your loop using a float variables (i), they need to be straight integers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `months[i]` as an index can't be of float type (e.g. what would the 4.5th item be?) so you'd have to convert it into an integer. The easiest way to achieve this should be replacing `months[i]` with `months[int(i)]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use one variable in two incompatible ways: as both the list index *and* the corresponding value.  Try this:

```
for mon in range(12): #----float
    i = net[mon]
    if i > average: #---also float
        good.append(i)
        goodmonths.append(months[mon])
    elif i < average:
        bad.append(i)
        badmonths.append(months[mon])
```

**mon** is the list index; **i** is the value from **net**.  You should change these to desscriptive variable names.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the value in `net` where you need to use the index, to get the corresponding element from the `months` array. Use `enumerate()` to get the indexes and values when looping:

```
for i, val in enumerate(net):
    if val > average:
        good.append(val)
        goodmonths.append(months[i])
    else:
        bad.append(val)
        badmonths.append(months[i])
```

BTW, your code completely ignores the case where the value is exactly equal to the average. The opposite of `>` is `<=`, not `<`. But if there are just two cases, use `else` rather than `elif`.